# Animating a box in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate a box in Jquery. Basically I'm just trying to to get the box to
move in a square path. I can get it to move right, and then down, but it doesn't do anything after that. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#box').css({'height':'100px','width':'100px','background-color':'black', 'position':'absolute','marginTop':'70px'});

  $('#box').animate({'left':'1000px'},3000,'swing', function(){
    $('#box'). animate({'top':'500px'},3000,'swing',function(){
    $('#box'). animate({'right':'1000px'},3000,'swing')
   })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `'left':'0px'` instead of `'right':'1000px'`.Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box').css({'height':'100px','width':'100px','background-color':'black', 'position':'absolute','marginTop':'70px'});
$('#box').animate({'left':'1000px'},3000,'swing', function(){
$('#box').animate({'top':'500px'},3000,'swing',function(){
$('#box').animate({'left':'0px'},3000,'swing')
})})});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqcbL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Small edit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#box').css({'height':'100px','width':'100px','background-color':'black', 'position':'absolute','marginTop':'70px'});

  $('#box').animate({'left':'1000px'},3000,'swing', function(){
    $('#box').animate({'top':'500px'},3000,'swing',function(){
      $('#box').animate({'left':'0px'},3000,'swing');
    });
  });
});
```